# How to understand function reduceLeft?

Tags: scala

Why can `(1 :: xs)`  be inserted?
One is cons'd onto beginning of list xs.

So `List(3,2,1)` becomes `List(1,3,2,1)` but what is significance of `(1 :: xs)`?

I'm having trouble understanding how this works :

```
def product(xs : List[Int]) = (1 :: xs) reduceLeft((x , y) => x * y)
```

In method signature a prefix operand (in this case `(1 :: xs)`) is not described? :

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](f: (B, A) => B): B =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(1 :: xs)` is not a prefix operand.

You are actually adding 1 before your list xs.

So `product(List(3,2,1))` becomes `List(1,3,2,1) reduceLeft((x,y) => x * y)`.

The reduceLeft function will take the 2 elements on the left and replace by the result of your function `(x,y) => x * y`.

In your case

List(1,3,2,1) => takes (1,3) and replaces by 1* 3 = 3 new List: List(3,2,1)
List(3,2,1) => takes (3,2) and replaces by 3 *2 = 6 new List: (6,1)
Finally takes (6,1) and get the final result 6.

As multiplying by one has no effect in the product, we add the number 1 before the List to avoid an error if the List is Empty.

Remove that and try `product(List())` and you will see. If the List had at least on element (1::xs) will have no effect in your function

Answer (score 0):

I believe you understand cons just fine.  `(1 :: xs)` is simply another way to express `List(1,3,2,1)`, on which you then invoke `reduceLeft`.

As for a better understanding of `reduceLeft`, I recently [blogged this exact topic](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/09/09/map-reduce-and-fold-for-the-programmatically-imperative/).

Answer (score 0):

That's not a prefix operand--it's a [method invocation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) on a List instance. The method reduceLeft is being called on the List (1 :: xs).

```
(1 :: xs) reduceLeft((x , y) => x * y)
```

can also be written as

```
(1 :: xs).reduceLeft((x , y) => x * y)
```

Or, even more explicitly:

```
val myList = (1 :: xs)
myList.reduceLeft((x , y) => x * y)
```